# What grants should I give to allow `COPY ... TO STDOUT`?

Tags: postgresql

**Context**

I want to set up a logical replication between two postgresql instances.

I created a `replication` user on the master instance :

```
CREATE ROLE replication WITH REPLICATION PASSWORD '$REPLICATIONPASSWORD' LOGIN;
```

Then a publication / subscription :

```
-- on the master instance :
CREATE PUBLICATION mypub FOR TABLES table1, table2, ...

-- on the slave instance :
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION mysub CONNECTION 'dbname=mydb host=localhost port=1234 user=replication password=...' PUBLICATION mypub;
```

**Issue**

In postgres' logs, I see error messages indicating that the replication user can't copy the tables :

```
-- on the slave side : message repeated for each table
ERROR:  could not start initial contents copy for table "public.table1": ERROR:  permission denied for table table1

-- on the master side : message repeated for each table
ERROR:  permission denied for table table1
STATEMENT:  COPY public.table1 TO STDOUT
```

Connecting with `psql` to the master server with the `replication` user I do see that `COPY table1 TO STDOUT` is rejected.

**Question**

What other privileges should I add to the `replication` user to allow `COPY ... TO STDOUT` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replication user needs to read the tables:

```
GRANT SELECT ON table1, table2, ... TO replication;
```

This must of course be run on the logical replication primary server.

Comment: You are right, and it was actually mentioned in [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/logical-replication-security.html). I'm a bit surprised that a user with `REPLICATION` access additionally needs access rights on individual tables.

Comment: It is not required for streaming replication, since that ready only WAL, but logical decoding has to do more work.